# How can i access :: Hasql.Pool.Pool inside :: BasicAuthCheck User?

Tags: servant, hasql

I usually pass `:: Hasql.Pool.Pool` to `serve` function as an argument through `run` as an argument from `main :: IO ()`

But ever since I started planning to use `:: BasicAuthCheck User` for authentication, I started needing `:: Hasql.Pool.Pool` inside `:: BasicAuthCheck User` which contains the `:: BasicAuthData -> IO (BasicAuthResult User)`.

My current workaround is to create another `:: Hasql.Pool.Pool` inside the `:: BasicAuthData -> IO (BasicAuthResult User)` and use it to authenticate users.

Is there a more elegant way than creating another connection pool?

Comment: I don't think it is as much related to Hasql, as it is to handling outside resources from `BasicAuthCheck`. Unfortunately I am no expert in Servant.

Comment: It is OK, I'm passing pool as a parameter to context.